# How to localize orbitals in pDynamo (CHARMM/ORCA interface)?

Tags: software, orca, pdynamo, charmm, qmmm

Does anyone know how to localize orbitals in pDynamo (CHARMM/ORCA interface). I am trying to identify the correct orbitals to swap for my high-spin iron(IV) system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the most consistent way to localize orbitals. Use the orca_loc extension. You must create and input file where define the localization method (PM, Boys, ...), and the orbitals you want to localize. To run it: orca_loc name.inp -i

Comment: what is the keyword for localization in the input file?

Comment: %loc LocMet PM end         PM is one of the localization methods.